# remaining in implementation of "RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I wrote this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
VOLUME /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

when I write

```
docker build -t myapache .
```

It remains in the implementation of below section and does not change.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2
```

[image]

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's stuck there because the `apt-get` waits for user interaction.

Try setting an environment variable telling the `apt-get` not to query any interactive question prompt. The env variable's name is `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` and the value should read `noninteractive`.

So try to prepend a line like:

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

before your `RUN` dockerfile directive.

Comment: @Golnoosh: Consider marking the answer as accepted as the solution worked for you. Thanks